# socket module sending and receiving Type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

```
>>> client.send('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> client.send('hello').encode()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> client.send('hello').encode('utf-8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

the client is connected and in receive mode `data=mysocket.recv(2048)`,i tried encoding the string but doesn't seem to work, i also tried to send integer values but got the same error. 
this is receiver

```
import socket
mysocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(('192.168.*.**',4444))
data=mysocket.recv(2048)
```

i had to ** the Ip-address

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('192.168.*.**',4444))
s.listen(5)
(client,(ip,port))=s.accept()
client.send('hello world')
```

how can i fix?

Comment: Try client.send(b'hello')

Comment: @kantal `>>> client.send(b'hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host`

Comment: @kantal although i haven't closed the receiver

Comment: what is your code?

Comment: @kantal updated

Comment: i've edited the code below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My proposed code (not fully tested):

```
#SERVER
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind(('192.168.*.**',4444))
    s.listen(0)
    conn, client_addr= s.accept()
    print('The client:', client_addr, s.gethostbyaddr(client_addr[0]),'\n')

    with conn:
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)  
            print('received:',data)
            if not data: # 'data' will be empty '' if the client closed the connection.
                print("exit")
                break

            conn.sendall(b'Hello World!') 

#CLIENT
import socket

with socket.socket(SockParam.FAMILY, SockParam.TYPE) as mysocket:

    mysocket.connect(('192.168.*.**',4444))
    print("The connection is established.")    
    data=mysocket.recv(2048)

    for msg in ["python","stackoverflow"]:

        sock.sendall( bytes(msg,encoding="utf8") )
        ackn = sock.recv(1024)          # waiting for the server
        print("echoed:",ackn )
```

For examle you can send 4-byte integers in big endian:

```
sock.sendall( int.to_bytes(42,4,'big') )
```